# Should I compress in-memory C# objects for better performance?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance

I have an application (C#, WPF) that displays many financial charts with live data streaming from server. The data that is collected in-memory may grow to be a bit large, and I don't want to keep any data on disk.

Since the historical data itself doesn't change, but only added to, will it make sense to keep that data (which is stored in a collection object) in some compressed format?

Is it possible and can anyone recommend a good practice for it if so?

**UPDATE**

Some notes about performance and tradeoff: 
I am aware that compression will add a delay accessing the data, but, the user only needs fast updates on new data arriving. When accessing the data that was already rendered (for example, to study or re-render it) he doesn't require a quick response.

Comment: When you say "large", how large do you mean?

Comment: @HABJAN might be 10th of MB or 100th, why? Basically it is not a "problem" to handle this amount of data, but I want to keep the memory footprint of the app as tiny as possible

Comment: I strongly recommend using industrial solution. One example is KDB database that is great as in-memory storage.

Comment: There's no reason you should be worrying about 10-100K.  Unless this is some sort of mobile app, any computer nowadays should be able to handle that.

Comment: @Saul "I want to keep the memory footprint of the app as tiny as possible" it is strange requirement for financial app. Usually they care about speed of processing and latency. You can't make it both small and fast.

Comment: @Adam I was talking about 10-100MB

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Compressing and decompressing will make your application slower so for performance (speed) it is not a good option.
Compression is only useful when you are worried about available memory. It might be easier to store/swap the data to a temp folder.

The key to performance is measuring. Only take action when you have crunched the numbers.

Comment: @Erno but once displayed, there is hardly any access to the old data, so whats the performance price here?

Comment: You were suggesting to compress the data in memory. To display compressed data you will need to decompress it. That takes time. Sure when you have displayed it and no longer need to access it you could compress it but why not simply get rid of it as you don't need it any more? Again measure first, then start to do the math and ask for advise. Until then we're just guessing.

Comment: @Erno Thank you, I will measure, currently I know of this problem from other applications. For the discussion: I don't want to throw it away since I will need to access it, and I don't want to download it again. When I do access it thuogh, I can pay the price of delay (but not the bandwidth). 
I thought rendering the chart once, compress the data, and then just update the chart with new data arriving.

Comment: I would not compress the data and simply store it on disk. That way a restart of the application will be faster than re-downloading.

Comment: @Erno That does seems as a better solution. But doesn't reading from disk is slower then decompressing the object?

Comment: That depends on the size and complexity of the object. Still, when the application restarts (for any reason (crash, kill)) objects in memory are lost so you have to either re-download or load from disk.

Answer (score 6):

Compressing the data has advantages in terms of memory usage, but disadvantages in terms of making the data unusable (you'll have to decompress it to use it again), as well as taking up extra CPU.

The tradeoff point where this would become beneficial is difficult to know without a lot more information - it's up to you.  However, if you're not using this old, stale data, it may be better to just throw it away (ie: let it go out of scope/stop storing it) instead of compressing it.

Compression can be done via the classes in [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z72378a.aspx), and is fairly easy.  These classes, in general, don't perform very well, however, so you may want to also consider a third party alternative, such as [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Comment: As I wrote to Erno, I will use this data occasionally, at times that don't require quick response. I don't want to throw it away because then I will need to download it every time and bandwidth is more expensive.

Comment: @Saul: Then a disk-based cache seems like a potentially appropriate option.  Compression is unlikely to save you a ton of memory, but will have a fairly high CPU cost...

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.0, I recommend storing the historical data using Memory Mapped Files.  The VMM can move through files on disk without requiring you to read an entire file to get data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trade off between performance and memory footprint and also depends on the data structures you are using. "Generic" compression (ie. gzip, run-length encoding etc.) doesn't make sense for many types of data.

One approach that might be applicable to you is picking **a more appropriate data structure** that optimizes memory footprint - i.e. for your chart do you really have to store independent stock prices or can you live by just storing delta values? If the later is true you probably could reduce the bits needed for each data point. Another thing is re-occuring patterns that are needed in all charts - could you factor those out in a separate object used by all charts hence only instantiated once?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for better performance, compression is not the way to go. As long as your client host has enough memory to handle the data then keeping the data uncompressed will result in maximum performance. Compressing the data will require uncompression and compression algorithms to run whenever the data is accessed.

If you are running out of memory on the client host, then you will be in a situation where you are forced to compress stored data. Note, however, that this will only save memory when the data is compressed and Garbage Collection has collected the in memory objects that are not compressed. Because the data will need to be uncompressed to be utilized, this will never provide a solution for maxing out client RAM.

With all this kept in mind, .NET provides the System.IO.Compression namespace for performing gzip compression. If you need compression I would start by looking there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to code it yourself, space-efficient data structures exist that don't require decoding/decompression to be used. [Steve Hanov describes Succinct Data Structures](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=120) in his latest blog post. His example is a succinct trie but there's nothing stopping you from representing other objects and structures. He cites several alternative implementations.

Obviously, this isn't an out-of-the-box solution. You'll have to decide if it's worth the effort to build and test a succinct representation.